# MVC DropDownListFor not selecting a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlistfor

I've been searching and i just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong
I have a Drop Down List like this:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, new SelectList(ViewBag.DestinationStatusList, "Value", "Text", Model.Status), 
new { @id = "DestinationStatusDropDown", @class = "dropListSmall" })
```

ViewBag.DestinationStatusList is a select list that is correctly populated with possible values I - Inactive and A - Active.
Model.Status is currently "I", but it just doesn't select any value on the rendered drop down.

Tks

Comment: `Status` value should match to one of the option's `value` attribute value. Does it ? (check view source of SELECT)

Comment: Yes it does match...

Comment: Then this code should work ! Are you sure that the value of I-Inactive option is "I" ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok Figured out the problem

Inside the controller there was being created a 
`ViewBag.Status = ...` with the same options that i forgot to delete. When removed from code everything started working.

Anyway, thanks for the attention given to my question

Comment: Sire note - `DestinationStatusList` looks like its already `IEnumerable<SelectListIem>` so using `new SelectList(...)` is pointless and just creating another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListIem>`, and the last parameter (`Model.Status`) is also pointless